# Android hint not showing in edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

**Here my edit text**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Drawer With Swipe Tabs" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMobileNo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_edittext"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="0.9">
            </EditText>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/alarm1"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Here @drawable/login_edittext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:startColor="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/orange" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"

                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**Here my @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar**

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
</style>
```

Here android:hint is not visible in my edit text.

Comment: try to set hintcolor in <EditText>

Comment: Thank you.It works for me .

Comment: welcome bro. Happy to help you :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute `android:textColorHint` to change hint text color.

For example: I have used `android:textColorHint="#000000"` to set color `BLACK` as hint text color.

**Update your `EditText` as below:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editMobileNo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_edittext"
    android:textColor="@color/orange"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">
</EditText>
```

Hope this will help~